# how to keep adding files to files array with multiple button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Basically, i have an input element of type file:

```
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
</form>
```

Now for each click on the file button, the files array only keeps track of the files selected for current click, how do i make so it keeps track of all the files for every click?

Comment: I would be surprised if this is supported and could be done without using some special upload control (Flash, Silverlight, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add more `input` elements to the page.